# Basic Eigenvalue Question

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, rotations

The rotation matrix $$T=\left[\begin{array}{c c}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{array}\right]$$ has no eigenvectors as an operator $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$. Here $0<\theta<\pi$. But identifiying $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}^2$ and considering $\mathbb{C}$ as a complex inner product space, we have that $$T:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}\ ,\ \theta\mapsto e^{i\theta}$$ is representing the same map. That is, $T=L_{e^{i\theta}}$. But any complex inner product space, with a normal operator ($T$ is normal) acting on it, admits an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors for that operator. So what am I missing here?

Comment: You're not missing anything. You can multiply by $i$ in the complex numbers, which represents counter-clockwise rotation by $\pi/2$ radians. You can't do that with the reals. Changing the underlying field between $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$ results in vastly different properties.

Comment: So what's the eigenvector?

Comment: of what? $T$? that depends whether you're working over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$. If it's $\Bbb R$ it has none. If it's $\Bbb C$, the eigenvectors are $[1, i]^t$ and $[1,-i]^t$. You can normalize these to get an orthonormal basis.

Comment: But $\mathbb{C}$ is a $1$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, why am I so confused? Why are those the eigenvectors? I'm starting to get embarrassed over here!

Comment: It's not so helpful to think of $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}^2$ for this question. Instead, think of $T$ as a $2 \times 2$ matrix over $\mathbb{C}$, acting on $\mathbb{C}^2$ as a linear transformation, and then you get the eigenvectors in $\mathbb{C}^2$ given in the comment of @Bryan.

Comment: Thank you, I do understand this. I just feel like this is completely transforming the problem. I'm just trying to find the eigenvalues of a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^2$. This is represented by $[e^{i\theta}]:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$, a normal linear operator on a complex inner product space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two possible interpretations here. Either you mean that this represents a linear map $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ by $z \mapsto e^{-i\theta}z$ in which case the problem is quite simple: without even invoking the algebraic completeness of $\mathbb{C}$, for *any* field $F$, a "linear map" $T:F \to F$, can be completely decscribed by the data $T(1) = \lambda \in F$, as we have that for any $z \in F$

$$ T(z) = zT(1) = \lambda z$$

Where we just use the fact that in one dimension we can just identify the vector space $F$ with the scalars $F$ and pull anything out. To get to the punchline, any linear map $F \to F$ is all eigenvectors, as it is completely described as just multiplication by $T(1)$. So in our example the eigenvectors are everything (except 0, depending on your definition), and the eigenvalue is $e^{i\theta}$.

Alternatively, the matrix $$T = \begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{pmatrix}$$
Can be viewed as a $2 \times 2$ complex matrix specifying a linear map $\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2$. To detect eigenvalues compute the characteristic polynomial

$$ \det(\lambda I - T ) = \det \begin{pmatrix} \lambda - \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & \lambda - \cos\theta \end{pmatrix} =  \lambda^2 - 2\lambda\cos\theta + 1 $$

So just use the quadratic formula to find eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks! So what is the difference between thinking of a rotation as a map on $\mathbb{R}^2$, for which no element is an eigenvector, and $\mathbb{C}$, for which every element is an eigenvector. Why is it wrong to think of the map $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ as a rotation of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Because the definition of eigenvector for a map $T: V \to V$ is that $Tv = \lambda v$ for some $\lambda$ *in the base field*. As a map of real vector spaces, a map only has eigenvectors if there is some vector that actually stretches by a real number. In complex vector spaces, a vector $v$ such that $Tv = iv$ is also an eigenvector, but if we forgot the complex structure, this would no longer be an eigenvector.

Comment: I get it now, thank you!